# 'NSInvocationOperation' is unavailable in Xcode 6.1

Tags: swift, ios8, nsinvocationoperation

My code suddenly can't be compiled in Xcode 6.1 (I'm sure it's working in Xcode 6 GM and beta version). It shows the error message:

> 'NSInvocationOperation' is unavailable

My code is:

```
let operation = NSInvocationOperation(target:self, selector:"backgroundRun:", object:self)
```

Can anybody help? Thanks.

Comment: The [8.1 API differences](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/iOS81APIDiffs/modules/Foundation.html) list `NSInvocationOperation` as having been removed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As of Xcode 6.1, `NSInvocation` is disabled in Swift, therefore, `NSInvocationOperation` is disabled too. See [this thread in Developer Forum](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1053221#1053221)

> Because it's not type-safe or ARC-safe. Even in Objective-C it's very very easy to shoot yourself in the foot trying to use it, especially under ARC. Use closures/blocks instead.

You have to use `NSBlockOperation` in Swift.

or `addOperationWithBlock` to `NSOperationQueue`

```
queue.addOperationWithBlock { [weak self] in
    self?.backgroundRun(self)
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm using it now.

Comment: `NSInvocation` was actually never available in Swift. `NSInvocationOperation` was only removed in iOS 8.1 SDK.